# Can I add a floating column to a Sheets query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Sheet like [this [minimal] example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VOqWKJlIlBNGnKAqL3PEkKxUNYqADw_CigokJUIIfg4/edit?usp=sharing). The "Data" tab is a running list of points different groups have scored. This is constantly updating. The "Results" tabs gets a list of all the unique group names from the Data tab and add them as a row in Column A. So, if an entry for "Group5" is entered on the Data tab, a row with that name will appear on the Results tab. Similar for the columns on the results tab. Each unique action on the Data tab becomes a column on the results tab.
I would like to add a "Total" column to the last column on the Results tab. The problem is, if a new "action" category appeared on the data tab, it would take up the last column and the Total column would need to shift over one. Is there a way to get the "Total" column to float so that it is always on the end without conflicting with the query formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B1` cell put below formula-

```
={TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(QUERY(Data!C2:C, "SELECT C where C is not null",0))),"Total"}
```

In `B2` cell put below formula then drag down and right as needed.

```
=IF(OR($A2="",B$1=""),"",IF(B$1="Total",SUMIFS(Data!$D$2:$D,Data!$B$2:$B,$A2),
SUMIFS(Data!$D$2:$D,Data!$C$2:$C,B$1,Data!$B$2:$B,$A2)))
```

[image]